# Issue installing Redmine

Tags: centos, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on a asmallorange.com server. It comes installed with ruby and rails.
I started with a bundle install

```
user@server.com [~/public_html]# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.4)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.7.2)
Using activesupport (3.2.13)

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cach
e/builder-3.0.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing builder (3.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install builder -v '3.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then typed in gem install builder -v '3.0.0'

```
user@server.com [~/public_html]# gem install builder -v '3.0.0'
Successfully installed builder-3.0.0
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for test/performance.rb, skipp
ing
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
1 gem installed
user@server.com [~/public_html]#
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

**I'd suggest you to delete the cache files from " \RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\cache " and rerun  bundle install.**